# Akamai Pull CDN Redirect from Origin Server

Tags: http, cdn, akamai

We got an Akamai Pull CDN setup on our server (we can not control Akamai settings) and we want to redirect from the origin server to the Akamai CDN URL so the URL the enduser has in the browser is always the Akamai URL thus that is the URL that gets shared even if there are legacy Links to the origin Domain itself.

But when we would redirect all requests we would also redirect Akamai itself. Is there any header or anything that identifies the Akamai crawlers? I couldn't find any information about this online. The documentation on Akamai says you should setup a CNAME on the old domain to the Akamai CDN but this is something we can't do as we can't control the origin URL to something different then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Professional Services support, they can add a custom header when going forward to the origin. Then you can key redirects based on the absence of this header.

If your configuration uses Property Manager you can add a custom outgoing header yourself.

If your config uses Configuration Manager, you could enable the X-True-ClientIP header via QuickStart additional features.